# condition in powershell - disk usage

Tags: powershell

I made a powershell script that displays the disk size and free space in GB and percent.
How to make a condition here, so that after reaching 51%, a message is displayed that there is not enough space?

```
$props = @(
    'DriveLetter'
    
    
    @{
        Name = 'SizeRemaining'
        Expression = { "{0:N2} GB" -f ($_.SizeRemaining/ 1Gb) }
    }
    @{
        Name = 'Size'
        Expression = { "{0:N2} GB" -f ($_.Size / 1Gb) }
    }
    @{
        Name = '% Free'
        Expression = { "{0:P}" -f ($_.SizeRemaining / $_.Size) }
    }
)

Get-Volume -DriveLetter C | Select-Object $props 


if ( $_.SizeRemaining -lt 50 )
{
    Write-Host "warning"
}
else {
    Write-Host ("ok")
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could just add another property to your output with the warning message in it.  For example, add a `Status` property like this:

```
$props = @(
    'DriveLetter',    
    @{
        Name = 'SizeRemaining'
        Expression = { "{0:N2} GB" -f ($_.SizeRemaining/ 1Gb) }
    },
    @{
        Name = 'Size'
        Expression = { "{0:N2} GB" -f ($_.Size / 1Gb) }
    },
    @{
        Name = '% Free'
        Expression = { "{0:P}" -f ($_.SizeRemaining / $_.Size) }
    },
    @{
        Name = 'Status'
        Expression = { if(($_.SizeRemaining / $_.Size) -lt 0.5){"Low"}else{"OK"} }
    }
)
```

So, you can just do this to see all the information at once:

`Get-Volume -DriveLetter C | Select-Object $props | Format-Table -AutoSize`

Which gives output like this:

```
DriveLetter SizeRemaining Size      % Free Status 
----------- ------------- ----      ------ ------ 
          C 121.33 GB     464.14 GB 26.14% Warning
```

As it's just another property, you can access/manipulate it like any other property.  For example, if you had lots of volumes on the system, you could just show the one with low space like this:

```
Get-Volume |
    Select-Object $props |
    Where-Object Status -eq 'Warning' |
    Format-Table -AutoSize
```